# PHP Call to a member function find()

Tags: php, parsing

**[Code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WuVvFqpb)**

**[Link on test page](http://testwork.ru/Tempp/parse_domains.php)**

**Code:**

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$file = 'http://testwork.ru/Tempp/domains.php'; // page with table

$SymbolsCountMin = 0;
$SymbolsCountMax = 10;

$SymbolsBackLis = array('-','_','.','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

$ArrTr = array();
$ArrTd = array();

$ch = curl_init($file);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    //$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    //var_dump($html);

//$html = file_get_html('http://testwork.ru/Tempp/domains.php');

// Find all tr 
$row = 0;
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr){
    if($row!=0){
        $row++;
        $column = 0;
        foreach($tr->find('td') as $td){
            $column++;
            $text = $td->plaintext;

            $ArrTd[$column] = $text;
        }
    }
    if(iconv_strlen($ArrTd[0]) > $SymbolsCountMin && iconv_strlen($ArrTd[0]) < $SymbolsCountMax && !in_array($ArrTd[0], $SymbolsBackList)){
        $ArrTr[$row] = $ArrTd;
    }
}

$c = '';

foreach($ArrTr as $arr_tr =>$ftr){
    $c .='<tr>';
    foreach($ftr as $arr_td =>$ftd){
        $c .='<td>';
        $c .= $ftd;
        $c .='<td>';
    }
    $c .='</tr>';
}

$row_header = '    
<table style="text-align:center;">
';

$row_header .= $c;

$row_header .= '
</table>';

echo $row_header;
```

*I get error* `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/seo-main/data/www/testwork.ru/Tempp/parse_domains.php on line 34`

*Tell me please why i get it error and how make right ?*

Comment: may be your `$html` is null or the `<td>` or `<tr>` is null check if it empty or not before using it

Answer (score 0):

`find()` is a member function of 
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You have commented out the line

```
$html = file_get_html('http://testwork.ru/Tempp/domains.php');
```

With `CURL` it will return html content not the parsed data.

If you are intend to use CURL then use

```
$html_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$html = str_get_html($html_data ); // using the returned html from curl to the parser
```

Then do the rest of the parsing part.

Comment: Tell me please for `file_get_html()` parametr `allow_url_fopen` should been On?

Comment: when i make ` $html_data = curl_exec ($ch); curl_close ($ch); $html = str_get_html($html_data);` i get this error too. full vesion new code http://pastebin.com/sbAxhRJP

Comment: And no u should not get that error. You are using CURL to get the html and then loading the returned data check here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm

Comment: ` var_dump($html_data) ` show table in array but problem with `find()` remain.. i make when show on example but i get error too... may be problems on hosting...

Comment: well u need to make sure that dom parser is available to your hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the code like this:

```
// Find all tr 
$row = 0;
if(!$html) { // check if $html does exists
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr){
    if($row!=0){
        $row++;
        $column = 0;
        foreach($tr->find('td') as $td){
            $column++;
            $text = $td->plaintext;

            $ArrTd[$column] = $text;
        }
    }
    if(iconv_strlen($ArrTd[0]) > $SymbolsCountMin && iconv_strlen($ArrTd[0]) < $SymbolsCountMax && !in_array($ArrTd[0], $SymbolsBackList)){
        $ArrTr[$row] = $ArrTd;
    }
}
}
```

or use a try and catch statement